# Online Viewer Walkthrough Autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am following this tutorial for online viewer.
https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview

I am using Visual Studio Code as text editor.
Every thing looks installed correctly. I am trying within 30 minutes of two legged authentication, even though this code is supposed to regenerate the token, after 30 minutes.
Strange in debugging FORGE_CLIENT_ID is showing "undefined"

When I am running the code, first it is giving an error at line 107

```
c:\Users\Tahmina\Downloads\viewer-walkthrough-online.viewer-master\viewer-walkthrough-online.viewer-master\start.js:107
const bucketKey = FORGE_CLIENT_ID.toLowerCase + '_tutorial_bucket'; // Prefix with your ID so the bucket key is unique across all buckets on all other accounts
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Tahmina\Downloads\viewer-walkthrough-online.viewer-master\viewer-walkthrough-online.viewer-master\start.js:107:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Then I removed "toLowerCase" 
and wrote the line as

```
const bucketKey = FORGE_CLIENT_ID + '_tutorial_bucket';
```

This way it showed "Server listening on port 3000"
and the page "authorize me!" in localhost.
But when I pressed the button , authorization failed. That means, the bucket creation failed.

Please let me know, why the line number 107 was showing error.

Am I missing something ?
Strange in debugging FORGE_CLIENT_ID is showing "undefined". I did run Cygwin terminal and generated token in right way and my app is open in forge account.

Looks like npm start is not working

log file is as below "

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:418:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:373:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:416:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:90:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:237:13)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Tahmina\Downloads\viewer-walkthrough-online.viewer-master
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v10.16.3
9 verbose npm  v6.9.0
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I am not using git. so far understood, npm package.json is created in wrong directory. I did npm init, so it create package.json in working folder,, it did. but still there is missing link. Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to try the sample project [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs) - see how it works and go from there. You can also follow the tutorial on [LearnForge](http://learnforge.autodesk.io) to start over from another perspective.

There are starter samples of different languages available [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels) so you can pick one you know best - since Forge (with the exception of the Viewer library which is obviously entirely JavaScript) is 100% RESTful so it's basically language neutral.

If you'd like to stick with Node.JS you can follow the tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/) (or any of the popular ones out there if you google them up) to wrap your head around the basics first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes on that day I could work out , Dot net version in 2 hours. I think node.js version tutorials has some missing part for node.js side or I am missing something, I am sure a very small compatibility issue or I missed one small step. So I am keeping node.js aside for now. I am in hurry. I just needed a basic interactive 3d viewer for now, to show  some one. It is working for now in Dot net environment. So I am safe for now :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but after I declared the environment var with the commands

```
set FORGE_CLIENT_ID = yourforgeclientid
set FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET = yourforgeclientsecret
```